# Transferring specific data from specific columns and specific rows from one df2 onto another df2 in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

df1:

- id, Name, Lastname, Account, ProofID1, ProofID2, status
- 1,  ab1,  dc1,  312,  1224,  111,  3
- 2,  ab2,  dc2,  434,  1225,  112,  4
- 3,  ab3,  dc3,  578,  1226,  111,  3
- 4,  ab4,  dc4,  624,  1227,  112,  4
- 5,  ab5,  dc5,  684,  1228,  113,  5

---

I am trying to design a function to copy specific columns according to their statuses.

I have designed a for loop, but I am unable to write the code for copying the data.

---

- for Name,Lname,Acc,ID1,ID2,status in   df1[['Name','Lastname','Account','ProofID1','ProofID2','status']].itertuples(index=False):
- if status==3:      #for df3
            #piece of code
- elif status== 4:   #for df4
           #piece of code
- elif status== 5:   #for df5
            #piece of code

---

Expected output:

- df2: (for status= 3)
- id, Name, Account, ProofID1, ProofID2
- 1,  ab1,  312,  1224,  111,  3
- 3,  ab3,  578,  1226,  111,  3

---

- df4: (for status= 5)
- id, Name, Account, ProofID1, ProofID2
- 5,  ab5,  684,  1228,  113,  5

Comment: Please look into the question I haven't found a solid piece on this line.

Comment: the solution gives all the statuses, but I want specific ones.